# How do you get `git grep` to return results without a pager?

Tags: git

How do you get `git grep` to return results without a pager? Grep does this by default. When I pipe `git grep` to cat: `git grep foo | cat` it does this but it loses the highlighting on the match. I want to keep the highlighting on the match without doing `git grep foo | cat | grep foo`.

Comment: You could configure the pager.grep options like this: ``` git config --global pager.grep false ```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can either use the `--no-pager` parameter like `git --no-pager grep foo` or tell grep to always do the highlighting even if you pipe the result to some other process with `git grep --color=always foo | cat`. Or you can set the config option `core.pager` to `cat` like `git -c core.pager=cat grep foo` or of course permanently with `git config core.pager cat` which will then work for all Git commands that would be sent to the pager and also preserves the highlighting.

***NOTE:*** `--no-pager` is a parameter to `git`, not to the subcommand, so do not write it after the sub-command.